# MsieJavaScriptEngine w3wp.exe on IIS

Tags: windows, iis

My application not work on IIS server. It works on local.

```
    Application: w3wp.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.IActiveScriptParse64.ParseScriptText(System.String, System.String, System.Object, System.String, IntPtr, UInt32, MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ScriptTextFlags, System.Object ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.EXCEPINFO ByRef)
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptParseWrapper.ParseScriptText(System.String, System.String, System.Object, System.String, IntPtr, UInt32, MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ScriptTextFlags)
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptJsEngineBase.InnerExecute(System.String, Boolean)
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptJsEngineBase+<>c__DisplayClass27_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<InvokeScript>b__0()
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ScriptDispatcher+<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<Invoke>b__0()
   at MsieJavaScriptEngine.ScriptDispatcher.StartThread()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```